# Loading transformed excel data from Power Query into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, powerbi

I am working on a little Power BI Project. The data source for this project is mostly excel files with untransformed dynamic data.

Initially I used these Excel sheets as the data source and transformed them in PowerQuery prior to building the datamodel. However, now there is a need to load the historical data into SQL server and connect Power BI to SQL as the data source.

Since the source files are not cleaned and transformed prior to importing them into Power Query, I cannot import them directly using the SSIS package - foreachloop container for multiple dynamic files.

Is there a way I can get the data back into SQL Server from PowerQuery after transformation? Is this where PowerQuery Source come into picture? What does it do exactly?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that PowerQuery Source will be the best choice in your case. There is a [good article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/power-query-source?view=sql-server-ver15) on Microsoft explaining it.

You will need to to three steps:

1. For each file which you use as a source, create a connection with PowerQuery type in SSIS connection manager;
2. Using PowerQuery source, copy the full query from Power BI advanced query editor to the "Query" field in the source settings;
3. On "Connection Managers" tab of the source, map each power query source (each file) with the corresponding connection which you created in step 1.

The output of this source is a list of columns which you can write to the DB using usual data flow task appraoch (like mapping this source to OLE DB destination)